# How do I get HTML page from a website with AJAX request without getting CORS error?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to do basic webscraping with javascript code using XMLHttpRequest. The code is triggered when I click on a button in an html page that I open with my Firefox browser.

The code I'm using is below. It tries to get the html page from ATP tour website and to print it as first step. Then I will try to parse it to get the information I want (like a rank for example).

```
let htmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
htmlRequest.open("GET", "https://www.atptour.com/en/players/matteo-berrettini/bk40/overview");
htmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
};
htmlRequest.send();
```

I discovered that running this code on localhost does not work because I'm not on the same domain as the site I'm sending my request (it is the classical CORS issue).

I now understand I need to create a web server but my understanding of the problem stops here.

So my question is: what do I have to implement to make my js script working?

Comment: [Cross Origin Ressource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: Well you can't web scrape from a browser. Of course you'll get CORS issues, that's a security feature. So the answer is yes, you need to do it from a script running in Node or something

Comment: Thanks for answering @JeremyThille. Well I actually understand that I need to run my script within the contexte of a server like Node can do. 
Could you point some options or features of Node that I should look for to allow cross origin resource sharing?

Comment: Just use Javascript's native `await fetch(url)`. Although available in browsers, for some reason Fetch is not directly implemented in Node, but available via the `node-fetch` package. I've found it more reliable and simpler to use than Axios.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried a web-scraping library? These are a few:

- [Apify](https://github.com/apify/apify-js)
- [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer)
- [Cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/)

Comment: Hi devananda, I've not tried to use a library as my goal is just to get one information in the html page. When I said web-scraping, it was just to say "get one information from html", but not a huge amount of information. 
Thanks for the tip though, I will consider the advised library if I pretend to do more than juste getting more than one or two info from a web page.

Comment: `"get information from html"` is the definition of web scraping :)